# how to do a 301 redirect in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i have this links and i want when someone goes to it to be redirected:

```
http://www.xxxxx.com/model_me.php?id=16
```

i did this, but id doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=16$
RewriteRule ^/model_me.php$ http://www.xxxxx.com? [L,R=301]
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the leading slash in the RewriteRule as below

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=16$
RewriteRule ^model_me.php$ http://www.xxxxx.com? [L,R=301]
```